# Unable to connect server via parse dashboard?

Tags: parse-server, parse-dashboard, alibaba-cloud

I have set up the parse-server and parse-dashboard in a dedicated instance on Alibaba Cloud with 2vCPU and 8GB of RAM with ApsaraDB for MongoDB as DB for Parse.
I successfully setup the dashboard and server. When I tried to access the server I get the following error,
"Unable to connect to server."

#### Parse Dashboard Error Screenshot

[image: Parse Dashboard Error Screenshot]

I am successfully able to make POST and GET Requests like below

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION_ID" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore

//Response
{
  "objectId": "2ntvSpRGIK",
  "createdAt": "2016-03-11T23:51:48.050Z"
}
```

I am able to connect via putty and FTP.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your computer (by that I mean other applications) is reaching the server the Parse dashboard isn't.

Inside your dashboard config you can try changing

`http://localhost:1337/parse`

to

`http://[ip-address]:1337/parse`

Also go through this thread, you might be able to get some more insight on why it is not working:
https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard/issues/785

Comment: Good catch!! Thanks a lot. I don't know how I missed this simple. Please upvote the question if you think this might helps others

Comment: not working
i have done, change to http://192.168.1.10:1337/parse, still not working